# Workbox 5 syntax error - Uncaught TypeError: workbox.expiration.CacheableResponsePlugin is not a constructor

Tags: workbox

I'm trying to set up a simple Service Worker for a small static site, but I get a service worker console error:

`sw.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: workbox.expiration.CacheableResponsePlugin is not a constructor`

This is at the line  `new workbox.expiration.CacheableResponsePlugin`

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

```
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:html)$/,
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
      cacheName: 'html-cache',
      plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.CacheableResponsePlugin({
          statuses: [0, 200],
        }),

        new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
          maxEntries: 50,
          maxAgeSeconds: 5 * 60,
        })
      ]
    })
  )
```

Comment: it's not under expiration, see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-cacheable-response.CacheableResponsePlugin

Comment: Thanks for responding  If you can give any further details that would be appreciated.

Comment: i mean visit that link, you see it isn't workbox.expiration.CacheableResponsePlugin but workbox-cacheable-response.CacheableResponsePlugin. expiration is the wrong module.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was migrating from `workbox` v4 to v5 and having the same problem.

In your code,

```
new workbox.expiration.CacheableResponsePlugin
```

should be

```
new workbox.cacheableResponse.CacheableResponsePlugin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Example: 

workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://assets.abcd.com/.*\.*'),
new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
cacheName: 'assets',
plugins: [
  new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
     statuses: [0, 200, 206] // 206 Partial Code. 
  }),
  new workbox.rangeRequests.Plugin()
]}))
```

Comment: Try to replace
`new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin` with `new workbox.cacheableResponse.CacheableResponsePlugin`

and `new workbox.rangeRequests.Plugin` with `new workbox.rangeRequests.RangeRequestsPlugin`

Answer (score 0):

its

```
new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin
```

now

Comment: In the accepted answer, it's noted that this changed between v4 and v5. I'm guessing this changed again. As with the accepted answer, it would be useful to specify between which versions this changed. That way, when people are reviewing this thread in a year or two, it's easier to understand under what context your answer is appropriate.

Comment: I dont have enogh reputation to comment :/

Comment: @Schlauewurst: No, but you can edit your answer to account for my suggestion above. That will make this answer more _useful_, and thus more likely to build your reputation.

Comment: Its not mention in any Docs i just figure it out by trial error.